# How do I use a wildcard in JWT unless?

Tags: node.js, express-jwt

I'm using express-jwt to secure my node application, and am wondering how I can use a wildcard in the unless parameter.  My working code is below, what I'd really like to do is open up access to anything that has a path starting with '/login' so I don't have to list every single resource.  When I add **'/login*'** to the **unprotected** array it ends up blocking /login with a 401/unauthorized.

Works:

```
// routes open to all
var unprotected = [
  '/login',
  '/login/app/main.js',
  'favicon.ico'
];

// configure jwt
var jwtCheck = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(config.get('auth0.secret'), 'base64'),
  audience: config.get('auth0.clientid')
});

// insert jwt middleware
app.use( jwtCheck.unless({path: unprotected}) );
```

Doesn't work:

```
// routes open to all
var unprotected = [
  '/login*',
  'favicon.ico'
];

// configure jwt
var jwtCheck = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(config.get('auth0.secret'), 'base64'),
  audience: config.get('auth0.clientid')
});

// insert jwt middleware
app.use( jwtCheck.unless({path: unprotected}) );
```

Comment: The module uses express-unless so what you have done should work, can you check the version etc?

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of express-unless (0.3.0) and express-jwt (3.4.0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The regexp needs to exist outside the quotes:

```
var unprotected = [
  /\/login*/,
  /favicon.ico/
];
```

Note that at this time with express-unless you can't mix regexp and strings in the same config array, which is why the second argument needs to have forward slashes instead of quotes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) and you will no need to write those ugly regExps by your own.

Sample below:

```
const pathToRegexp = require('path-to-regexp');

// Use JWT auth to secure the API
const unprotected = [
    pathToRegexp('/login*'),
    pathToRegexp('/favicon.ico')
];

app.use(expressJwt({ secret: config.tokenSecret }).unless({ path: unprotected }));
```