# Inserting password reset token to unprotected NodeJS route

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, authentication

I am currently trying to pass my password reset generated token inside my **unprotected** route but whenever I execute my **GET** request, I receive an `401 Unauthorized request`.

I've tried including the package **Path-to-RegExp** and constructing a separate array route but it didn't work:

```
let tokens = [];
const unprotected = [
  pathToRegexp('/user/reset/:token', tokens),
];
```

My **password-reset** token is generated in a separated service and called in a controller:

```
 const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
          user.update({
            resetPasswordToken: token,
            resetPasswordExpires: Date.now() + 360000,
          });
```

Here is how I've structured my `expressJwt` with `unless`:

```
app.use(expressJwt({
  secret: process.env.SECRET_BEARER,
  getToken: req => {

     MY TOKEN AUTHORISATION CODE IS PLACED HERE.
 }

}).unless({ path: ['/images/', '/user/password-reset', unprotected ]}));
```

---

My issue is that whenever I try to create a unauthenticated route such as `.unless({path: ['/images/', '/user/password-reset', '/user/reset/:token' ]}));` the route `/user/reset/:token` is only parsed as a string a the value of `:token` is not actually passed.

I've read some similar questions about passing it with regex or functions but I couldn't figure it out myself.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38821632/how-do-i-use-a-wildcard-in-jwt-unless) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842836/node-expressjwt-unless-specify-id-route) question have been particularly useful on how to approach the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `tokens` and `unprotected` if you `console.log` them?

Comment: [ /^\/user\/reset\/([^\/]+?)(?:\/)?$/i ] [ { name: 'token',
    prefix: '/',
    delimiter: '/',
    optional: false,
    repeat: false,
    pattern: '[^\\/]+?' } ]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a regex to unless, which you may have already realized since you tried to use Path-to-RegExp. You could also just try to write the regex yourself and pass it directly to unless. In your case your unless would look like this:

```
.unless({ path: [/\/images\//, /\/user\/password-reset\//, /^\/user\/reset\/[a-z0-9_-]*/]}));
```

**EDIT:** this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39283209/1035) suggest that you cannot combine regex and strings in the same array, so I've converted all paths to regex expressions.

Comment: It returns a `404` now for some reason, I don't think that this is matching properly.

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard what is the exact path that you are requesting?

Comment: I need to pass `/user/reset/:token` where `:token` is the value of my password reset token..

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard is the token alphanumeric with possible dashes and underscores? If so see my updated answer

Comment: yeah I've tried this but I keep receiving `404` on my get which points to `"http://localhost:3003/user/reset/" + tokenURL`

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard are you sure that tokenUrl is just the token and not accidentally an actual url (as the name suggests)? Could you console.log this tokenUrl?

Comment: `eae81f8ac64bd3e08c4ae7663419f1325519b624` whenever I console log the token. I'm sure it is because I'm passing it through a generated email and then passing the the token as props to my url.

Comment: I'm still getting a `404` for some reason. I think that when I switch all the paths to regex, it doesn't detect anything at all. It just returns a `404` for all paths. I'll look into this issue in more details, thanks for the support so far..

Answer (score 0):

You have an array within an array for the value of `path` passed into `unless`.

Change:

```
}).unless({ path: ['/images/', '/user/password-reset', unprotected ]}));
```

To:

```
}).unless({ path: unprotected }));
```

And change `unprotected` to include the other paths:

```
const unprotected = [
  '/images/',
  '/user/password-reset',
  pathToRegexp('/user/reset/:token', tokens),
];
```

Ensure you test with a path that includes a token e.g:
`/user/reset/123-some-real-looking-value`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me out, unfortunately this doesn't work at all. My built just fails

Comment: "My built just fails" doesn't help, edit your question to provide a complete simplified code sample and build errors.